# Using $ jQuery in Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, signalr

I have a very small and simple app that I have created from the JavaScriptServices ng2 starter kit (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices).

I want to connect to a signalr hub and am trying to do this in a service. I am trying to use the jquery $.hubconnection to do this however I am seeing an error saying...

> ```
> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> ```

I know this is because the jQuery lib cannot be found. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

The start of my service looks like this...

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

declare var $;

@Injectable()
export class SignalRService {

    private proxy;
    private proxyName: string = 'dateHub';
    private connection;

    public foodchanged: EventEmitter<any>;
    public connectionEstablished: EventEmitter<Boolean>;
    public connectionExists: Boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.foodchanged = new EventEmitter();
        this.connectionEstablished = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
        this.connectionExists = false;

        this.connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:5000/' + 'signalr/');
      //  this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);
      //  this.registerOnServerEvents();
      //  this.startConnection();
    }
```

My full code is at github at https://github.com/bencameron00/Ng2JQueryHub

I would really appreciate some help here. I am very stuck.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 
"jquery": "2.2.0" in packge.json then in command: npm i

then

> import 'jquery';

In your page

now $ will work

Comment: Thanks, I was already referencing   "jquery": "^2.2.4". Does the version make a difference?

Comment: And do you add the import to the service or index.html?

Comment: Better to inport it in polyfil/main.ts

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="assets/xx/jquery-xxx.min.js"></script>
</body>


declare var $: any;

@Component({})
```

Comment: I just tried that, thanks for the suggestion but it still fails.

Comment: It works for you using the my repo code as a base? Can you confirm please?

Comment: No , in my codebase which is completely angular-2 based.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)